# Manipulate showitem for tt_content Elements wihthin IRRE. Like in tx_news

Tags: typo3, tx-news

Is it possible to define the behavior of showitem for tt_content within IRRE (content_elements).
For example, I want to remove the header for all elements if they are added via tx_news.
columnsOverrides is the wrong approach beacause it's not a filed direktly of the news_record maybe there is a possibility with TCEFORM or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Page TSconfig in the tsconfig field of the sysfolder where your news are saved:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.header.disabled = 1
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html for the full docs

Comment: Thanks Georg Ringer. At the moment I can't think of any other option.
Now I have to find out how to save the relations in a separate folder because the news-records must stay in the old one.

Comment: @N1ck So use Georg's tip in _Page TSconfig_ of your folder, or if you want that behaviour to be default for all pages/folders, add this in _Page TSconfig_ of your root.

Comment: It shouldn't be the default behavior. only within the IRRE.
 However, the news must stay in the folder, there are also other tt_content elements which should not be changed.

Therefore the tt_content-relations for news records would have to be saved in a separate folder, but I have not yet found a solution for this. I could not find a solution for TCA inline and a separate pid